# Converting MySQL dateline to the unix timestamp.

Tags: php, mysql, unix-timestamp

My date in the MySQL is stored in the following format:

`2012-01-25 15:16:12`

Now I need to convert this dateline to the unix timestamp.
Is that possible in PHP?

Comment: It is of course possible in PHP (see Mchl's answer) and it's also possible in your query `SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_column) AS date_timestamp FROM ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strtotime('2012-01-25 15:16:12')`

Answer (score 6):

`SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_column) AS date_column FROM table` is also an option in MySQL.

Comment: Thank you. useful for the future (+1).